# Embed ASP.NET website within another ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.NET site (site 1) that has some UI that uses jquery to bind the data to controls and CRUD methods that perform database operations.

I would like to embed this ASP.NET site 1 into another ASP.NET site (site 2) such that when a user clicks a button/link on site 2, site 1 is loaded in a modal popup and the user on site 2 can perform all the actions that they would on site 1 within that popup. So site 1 is effectively a black-box for site 2.

I had thought of using an iframe in site 2 to load site 1, but I am not sure how I would pass parameters to site 1. Any help or alternate solutions would be much appreciated.

I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: Your question is too open-ended. Why don't you implement your idea using iframes or simple links (use querystring parameters to pass values) and seeing what works for you - then come back when you have a smaller, more well-defined, question that needs an answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to make JavaScript method calls from site 2 to site 1 and exchange data as well. I would like to use jquery or some other framework to do this and I was looking for some examples to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at FancyBox library. You should be able to do what you are trying with that.